# General Formula for Principle Square Root of Complex Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How can I prove that $ \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{|z|} \frac{(z + |z|)}{|z+|z||} $ without using mathematical induction, and if I cannot -- how would I go about using induction in the set of complex numbers ?

Comment: The complex numbers are uncountable and standard induction only works on countable sets.

Comment: @anorton countable well ordered sets.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure if there was an analogue -- that's why I wanted to prove this without induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we write $z = re^{i\theta}$ then $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ and we need to show that $$e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{re^{i\theta} + r}{|re^{i\theta} + r|} = \frac{e^{i\theta} + 1}{|e^{i\theta} + 1|}$$

Using double angle trigonometric identities we have:

$$
\frac{e^{i\theta} + 1}{|e^{i\theta} + 1|} = \frac{1+\cos\theta + i\sin\theta}{\sqrt{(1+\cos\theta)^2 + \sin^2\theta}} = \frac{2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2} + 2i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\sqrt{4\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}}} = \cos\frac{\theta}{2} + i\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}
$$

Comment: You should probably explain why $\sqrt{\cos^2 (\theta/2)} = \cos(\theta/2)$ (and not $-\cos(\theta/2)$). In other words, since we are looking for the **principal** square root, we choose $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: Does the formula given in the original post work for all square roots, not just the principal one ?

Answer (score 1):

Squaring the RHS, you get
$$|z| \frac{(z+|z|)^2}{|z+|z||^2} = |z|\frac{z^2+2z|z|+z\overline{z}}{(z+|z|)(\overline{z}+|z|)} = z\frac{2|z|^2+|z|(z+\overline{z})}{2|z|^2+|z|(z+\overline{z})}=z$$

Comment: This only shows that the expression is **a** square root, not necessarily the principal square root.

Comment: @mrf Isn't that a quick fix, as its phase will be that of $z+|z|$, which is $(\theta+0)/2$ for $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi)$.